# Different images for light/dark mode with Material for MkDocs

Tags: html, material-design, markdown, darkmode, mkdocs

I am writing documentation using [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) and [Material for MkDocs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/).

I would like to have an image inside `index.md` that switch between two different versions when I switch from light to dark mode and vice versa.

I've found different solutions online, but none of them seems to work.

```html
<picture>
    <source srcset='img/dark.png' media='(prefers-color-scheme: dark)'>
    <img src='img/light.png' alt="Docs logo">
</picture>
```

```css
>>> HTML
<div class="img-toggle"></div>

>>> CSS
.img-toggle {
  background: url(../img/light.png) center / cover;
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
  .img-toggle {
     background: url(../img/dark.png) center / cover;
  }
}
```

```markdown
>>> I think this is just for GitHub
![Docs logo](./img/dark.png#gh-dark-mode-only)
![Docs logo](./img/light.png#gh-light-mode-only)
```

Maybe it's just not implemented yet.
I hope someone can help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you added a color palette toggle and want to show different images for light and dark color schemes, you can append a #only-light or #only-dark hash fragment to the image URL:

```markdown
![Image title](https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f5f5f5/aaaaaa#only-light)
![Image title](https://dummyimage.com/600x400/21222c/d5d7e2#only-dark)
```

Reference: https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/images/#light-and-dark-mode